# Android layout with view on the right that takes up a pre-set space and view on the left scales to fill the rest of the screen up to a certain limit

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-screen, android-screen-support

I'm making a layout (XML file) in Android that has two child views (one on the right side of the screen and one on the left). I want the view on the right to take up a pre-determined space (in dp) and have the view on the left take up all the remaining space up to a limit, at which point it will stop expanding and the two layouts will just move further apart as the screen gets larger.

The odd thing is this would be very easy if I wanted the view on the right side to be the one that expands, and the view on the left to be the one that takes up a preset space. If you set each view to the width you want (in a horizontal linear layout) Android will automatically shrink the one on the left in the event that both views don't fit.

I would like to do this in one layout file; this layout is already designed for displays between sw512dp-land and sw765dp-land.

The code below would work if I could find a way to make Android shrink the layout on the left (when layouts both cannot fit at the size specified). But by default the system will shrink the layout on the right first.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/red" >
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/right"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/green" >
</LinearLayout>
```

This code (from @Lokesh) would work if I didn't need the layout on the left to stop expanding at a certain point.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right"
    android:background="@color/red" >

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/right"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/green" >
</LinearLayout>
```

It would also be nice to know if anyone thinks this isn't possible so I can resort to doing it pragmatically or changing my approach to the layout.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are these *views* you are talking about? I mean Layouts or widgets?

Comment: This should be easy to do but depends on what do you mean by *take up all the remaining space up to a limit*.

Comment: The views are layouts @LokeshMehra.

Comment: @Lukesprog, I mean depending on the exact display size of the device the app is running on. For example if the app is running on a device with a screen that's 500 dp wide I'd like the view on the left to be 250dp in width, if it's running on a screen that's 600 dp wide the view should be 350dp, but for 600 and up it should remain 350dp wide.

Comment: @chaitanya I'll update the post with some code that I've tried tomorrow. I've tried at least 30 different ways of doing it but I'll try to post a few that got the closest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me. I've set the right layout to 100dip, change as per your needs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right"
        android:background="@color/red" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/green" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT 1:** I used the background color just to distinctly show the layouts. Not necessary at all. :)

**EDIT 2:** If you want a way to expand the left layout upto only a limit then try this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right">
        <LinearLayout 
                            android:id="@+id/inner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"         
            android:background="@color/yellow">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/myTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="This will expand only to a limit"
                android:maxWidth="300dip"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
                android:background="@color/red" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/green" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here you need to place your widgets in `inner` layout and this is what it looks like in different screens.

**3.1in HVGA**
[image: 3.2in HVGA]

**5.2in QVGA**
[image: 5.2in QVGA]

Colors used : red(#FFFF00), yellow(#FFFFFF00), green(#FF00FF00).

Comment: Thanks, I added this and another example with the same layout IDs to the main post as references. The problem with this is the layout on the left will never stop expanding as the screen gets larger. If the layout on the left is assigned a dip value then when it stops expanding it will move away from the left side of the screen rather than a space growing between the two layouts.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can achieve what you want directly but if you place some `Widgets` in you layout this can be achieved by placing an inner Layout inside the left with `wrap_content` and then placing the `Widgets` with ``android:maxWidth`. Wait I will edit my answer.